# Get row data associated with maximum values in a column (Python / Pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Given the data below:

```
               Sum  amount_net  amount_gross    symbol  Date_Time
ts                  
7/29/2013 2:17  -68 755,101 -755,101        A   7/29/2013 2:17
7/29/2013 2:17  -21 251,945 -251,945        B   7/29/2013 2:17
7/29/2013 2:16  -1  2,200   -2,200          C   7/29/2013 2:16
7/29/2013 2:17  -5  11,000  -11,000         C   7/29/2013 2:17
7/29/2013 2:08  -1  5,384   -5,384          D   7/29/2013 2:08
7/29/2013 2:09  -3  16,151  -16,151         D   7/29/2013 2:09
7/29/2013 2:13  1   5,384   5,384           D   7/29/2013 2:13
7/29/2013 2:02  20  70,000  70,000          F   7/29/2013 2:02
7/29/2013 2:03  22  77,000  77,000          F   7/29/2013 2:03
7/29/2013 2:04  18  63,000  63,000          F   7/29/2013 2:04
7/29/2013 2:05  15  52,500  52,500          F   7/29/2013 2:05
7/29/2013 2:08  15  52,500  52,500          F   7/29/2013 2:08
7/29/2013 2:09  8   28,000  28,000          F   7/29/2013 2:09
7/29/2013 2:10  22  77,000  77,000          F   7/29/2013 2:10
7/29/2013 2:11  22  77,000  77,000          F   7/29/2013 2:11
7/29/2013 2:12  12  42,000  42,000          F   7/29/2013 2:12
7/29/2013 2:13  5   17,500  17,500          F   7/29/2013 2:13
7/29/2013 2:14  30  105,000 105,000         F   7/29/2013 2:14
7/29/2013 2:15  35  122,500 122,500         F   7/29/2013 2:15
7/29/2013 2:16  35  122,500 122,500         F   7/29/2013 2:16
```

I'd like to return for each symbol, the sum, amount_net and amount_gross at the maximum time for that symbol. ie I'd like to get:

```
symbol  Time           Sum  amount_net  amount_gross
A   7/29/2013 2:17  -68 755,101        -755,101
B   7/29/2013 2:17  -21 251,945        -251,945
C   7/29/2013 2:17  -5  11,000          -11,000
D   7/29/2013 2:13  1   5,384             5,384
F   7/29/2013 2:16  35  122,500         122,500
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort chronologically, group by symbol, and then take the last (which is to say "maximum time") element from each group.

```
In [28]: df.sort('Date_Time').groupby('symbol').last()
Out[28]: 
                 Date_Time  Sum  amount_net  amount_gross
symbol                                                   
A      2013-07-29 02:17:00  -68      755101       -755101
B      2013-07-29 02:17:00  -21      251945       -251945
C      2013-07-29 02:17:00   -5       11000        -11000
D      2013-07-29 02:13:00    1        5384          5384
F      2013-07-29 02:16:00   35      122500        122500
```

See @Andy's remark about parsing the numbers as integers.

Comment: It'll almost always (?) be faster to do the sort on each subframe: `df.groupby('symbol').apply(lambda x: x.sort().iloc[-1])`. Although probably a good idea to have the frame sorted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply groupby symbol and sum:

```
In [11]: df1.groupby('symbol').sum()
Out[11]:
        Sum  amount_net  amount_gross
symbol
A       -68      755101       -755101
B       -21      251945       -251945
C        -6       13200        -13200
D        -3       26919        -16151
F       259      906500        906500
```

Note: atm it looks like `amount_net` and `amount_gross` have not been parsed correctly as integers, rather they are strings, but you can convert using:

```
df1[['amount_net', 'amount_gross']] = df1[['amount_net', 'amount_gross']].applymap(lambda x: int(x.replace(',', '')))
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for the sum but for the maximum row by symbol (I think the maximum of `amount_net`, but I haven't checked to see if that fits.)

Comment: Good point! I'd misread that OP was looking for sum, rather than Sum and some other columns...